# the request does not pass on the verification base. I don't know what else to do((

Tags: sql

From the table `Output` for each point of reception to choose those issues of money, the size of which (out) has a value located between the average amount of issues for this point and their median.

Output: code distribution of money, code of item, size of issuance, the median size of the renditions for the item, the average value of the size of renditions for the item.

Note: the median sequence of any n numbers arranged in ascending order of their magnitudes is `x[1]`, `x[2],...,x[n]` - is called either `x[k]` if `n` is odd and equal to `2k-1`, or `(x[k] + x[k+1])/2` if `n` is even and equal to `2k`.

My Code:

```
with qqq as ( select distinct 
  code,
  point,
  out,
  (MAX(CASE WHEN Percent50_Asc=1 THEN out END) OVER (PARTITION BY point) +
  MIN(CASE WHEN Percent50_desc=1 THEN out END) OVER (PARTITION BY point))/2 
  MEDIAN,avg(out) over(partition by
  point) as AVGOUT
FROM
(
SELECT
  code,
  Point,
  out,
  NTILE(2) OVER (
    PARTITION BY point
    ORDER BY out ASC) AS Percent50_Asc,
  NTILE(2) OVER (
    PARTITION BY point
    ORDER BY out DESC) AS Percent50_desc
   FROM Outcome SOH
) x
) select * from qqq where MEDIAN < out and AVGOUT > out
```

Comment: What is this "verification base" you're talking about?

Comment: For SQL questions always detail the version of your RDBMS (add the appropriate tag to the question).

Comment: Please format your code to make it more readable. See the `where )`?

Comment: I can not even imagine what version of the site server EX-SQL...

Comment: "See the where )?".. correct

Comment: :(((((((((((((((